# Numbering a slice of string having same text

Tags: go

I have a slice of string containing some elements with the same text such as:
`[apple, banana, apple, peer, apple]`
what I would like to do is update the names of the string having the same text by number them in this way:
`[apple, banana, apple2, peer, apple3]`
how can I do this in a slice of strings?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Show us your code and tell us what you have tried and does not work or where you got stuck. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem in a very efficient manner: O(N)
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)
func main() {
    testStringSlice := []string{"apple", "banana", "apple", "peer", "apple"}
    outputStringSlice := numberItems(testStringSlice)
    fmt.Println(outputStringSlice)
}

func numberItems (arr []string) []string{
    m := make(map[string]int)
    for idx, item := range arr {
            if count, ok := m[item]; ok {
                    m[item] = count + 1
                    arr[idx] = item + strconv.Itoa(m[item])
            } else {
                    m[item] = 1
            }
    }
    return arr
}
```